# Controller for each fxml (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, controller, fxml

I want to set for each fxml one Controller. These controller should be able to interact, but I get always a `NullPointerException`. I have one fxml with a `Button` and one fxml with a `TextField`. If I press the `Button`, the `TextField` should append.
I have reduced the code a little bit. I know these questions is asked many times but, nothing work for me.

Here is my Code:
    Controller for the `LogStage.fxml`. Here is the `TextArea` where I would set the text.

```
public class LogController{
    @FXML private TextArea logTextAreaFx;
    public void handlelogTextAreaFX(ActionEvent event, String text){
        logTextAreaFx.appendText(text);
    }
}
```

Controller for the `MainStage.fxml`. The main window, with an `Button` who should set the `TextArea` if activated.

```
public class MainController{
    @FXML LogController logController;
    public void handleChatConsoleButton(ActionEvent event){
        logController.handlelogTextAreaFX(event, "test");
    }
}
```

LogStage.fxml:

```xml
<VBox prefWidth="500" prefHeight="300" id="logView" fx:controller="LogController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >
    <TextArea text="-------- Log ---------" id="logTextArea" fx:id="logTextAreaFx"></TextArea>
</VBox>
```

MainStage.fxml:

```xml
<VBox minHeight="520" minWidth="1280" fx:controller="MainController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <Button text="test Button" onAction="#handleChatConsoleButton"></Button>
</VBox>
```

The main Controller. These Controller should set all Controller and instantiates and start the `GameView`.

```
public class ClientController {
    private ClientView clientView;
    @FXML private MainController mainController;
    @FXML private LogController logController;
    public ClientController(){
        this.clientView = new ClientView();
    }
    public void showView(){
        this.clientView.startView();
    }
    public void setText(String text){
        logController.handlelogTextAreaFX(null, "hello world");
    }
}
```

These class starts the whole application.

```
public class GameMain {
    static ClientController controller;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        controller = new ClientController();
        controller.showView();
    }
}
```

The ClientView set all boxes and starts the fxml.

```
public class ClientView extends Application{
    VBox root = new VBox();
    VBox mainStage;
    public void startView(){
        launch();
    }
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        loadMainStage();
        loadLogStage();
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


     @FXML Pane MainStage;
    public void loadMainStage(){
        mainStage = new VBox();
        try {
            mainStage = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("MainStage.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        root.getChildren().add(mainStage);
    }
    @FXML VBox LogStage;
    public void loadLogStage(){
        //ClientController controller = new ClientController();
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        Pane root = new Pane();
        Scene chatScene = new Scene(root);
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle("Log View");
        stage.setScene(chatScene);
        stage.setResizable(true);
        try {
            //loader.setController(controller);
            LogStage = loader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("LogStage.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        root.getChildren().add(LogStage);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have already described the `fx:controller` in your FXML, you should fetch the controller instance from the FXMLLoader using [`loader#getController`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController())

Comment: `@FXML` fields in the controller are initialized by the `FXMLLoader` to the elements in the FXML file whose `fx:id` matches the name of the field. There is no element in `MainStage.fxml` with `fx:id=logController`, so `logController` is never initialized - i.e. it remains null and you get a NPE. It's really unclear how you would expect this to work anyway. Suppose you loaded `LogStage.fxml` twice, so you had two `LogController` instances. Which one would you expect the field in `MainController` to refer to?

Comment: Similarly, your `ClientController` and `ClientView` classes don't even seem to be a controller class for *any* FXML. In the `ClientView` class, you are initializing the fields in the usual way (assigning them values), so they should not be annotated `@FXML`. In `ClientController`, `mainController` and `logController` will always be null.